# How to "clear mocks" for the "@testing-library/react" fireEvent?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using `@testing-library/react` for testing an app with legacy code. Basically, each time I click a button is shown a message component. The message is the legacy code. This legacy component injects HTML in the DOM.

When a Test my application, I realized that the code injected by legacy code is not clear between the tests.

**Repos.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function showMessage() {
  const message = document.createElement('div');
  message.innerHTML = '<h1>Successfully saved!</h1>';
  document.body.appendChild(message);
}

export default function Repo() {
  const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);

  function handleOnClick() {
    setRepos([
      { name: 'Repo 1' },
      { name: 'Repo 2' },
    ]);
    showMessage();
  }

  return (
    <nav>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Show repos</button>
      <ul>
        {repos.map(repo => <li data-testid={repo.name} key={repo.name}>{repo.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

**Repos.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Repos from './Repos';
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';


describe('Repos', () => {
  describe('when clicking the button', () => {
    beforeEach(() => cleanup());

    it('should updates repos collection', () => {
      const { container, getByText, getByTestId } = render(<Repos />)

      fireEvent.click(getByText('Show repos'));

      expect(getByTestId('Repo 1')).toBeTruthy();
      console.log(container.innerHTML);
    });

    it('should show the success message component', () => {
      const { container, getByText } = render(<Repos />)

      fireEvent.click(getByText('Show repos'));


      expect(getByText('Successfully saved!')).toBeTruthy();
      console.log(container.innerHTML);
    })
  })
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may(and need) to clean `document` before each test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  document.body.innerHTML = "";
});
```

If by a chance your `showMessage` is in separate file, I'd suggest mocking it in your tests. This way you would also avoid testing its internals everywhere(except tests focused on `showMessage` itself for sure)